# Is there a wordpress function that I can use to retrieve the current page that is loaded?

Tags: permalinks, functions, page-template

Suppose that I create a page in the admin section (under 'Pages') and I have permalinks turned on and this pages slug is 'my-new-page', then is there a WordPress function that will work outside the (blog) Loop that I can use in that page's template on my theme that will retrieve that page's permalink?

Comment: get_permalink() ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi **@racl101:**

I think what you are after is to use **`get_page_link($post->ID)`**. The value `$post` will have been set by the default query to be equal to the post for the current page and should be in scope when your page template is run.

Comment: Also if your code is in a function, make sure that you make $post global.

Comment: @Manny Fleurmond - Good point.

Comment: @racl101 - You are welcome. :)

Answer (score 0):

yes first of all you would need to require wp-load.php in your custom area using this code:

```
 <?php
 require( '../my_wordpress_install_root/wp-load.php' ); ?>
```

And after that you can follow thsi tut to call any page : 
http://www.snilesh.com/resources/wordpress/wordpress-tips-and-tricks/wordpress-get-page-content-by-page-id/

Comment: The original question describes then need to call it outside the Loop, but still in WordPress templates - core would be loaded just fine as usual.